# Unable to get prosody running on Ubuntu 10.04 (lua issues)

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, aptitude, lua

All this is performed on **Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS** Server

- I installed LUA 5.1.4 following this procedure - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1874860
- I installed prosody following this command (after downloading the package) - sudo dpkg -i prosody_0.8.2-1_i386.deb

After installation, I get the following error:
I have tried to use as suggested luarock and sudo apt-get install to fix these. But still it keeps showing me these errors.

```
Selecting previously deselected package prosody. (Reading database ...
59416 files and directories currently installed.) Unpacking prosody
(from prosody_0.8.2-1_i386.deb) ... Setting up prosody (0.8.2-1) ... 
* Starting Prosody XMPP Server prosody
************************** Prosody was unable to find luaexpat This package can be obtained in the following ways:

        Source:           www[dot]keplerproject[dot]org/luaexpat/
        Debian/Ubuntu:    sudo apt-get install liblua5.1-expat0
        luarocks:         luarocks install luaexpat

luaexpat is required for Prosody to run, so we will now exit. More
help can be found on our website, at prosody[dot]im/doc/depends
**************************


************************** Prosody was unable to find luasocket This package can be obtained in the following ways:

        Source:           www[dot]tecgraf[dot]puc-rio[dot]br/~diego/professional/luasocket/
        Debian/Ubuntu:    sudo apt-get install liblua5.1-socket2
        luarocks:         luarocks install luasocket

luasocket is required for Prosody to run, so we will now exit. More
help can be found on our website, at prosody[dot]im/doc/depends
**************************


************************** Prosody was unable to find LuaSec This package can be obtained in the following ways:

        Source:           www[dot]inf[dot]puc-rio[dot]br/~brunoos/luasec/
        Debian/Ubuntu:    prosody[dot]im/download/start#debian_and_ubuntu
        luarocks:         luarocks install luasec

SSL/TLS support will not be available More help can be found on our
website, at prosody[dot]im/doc/depends
**************************

                                                                         [fail] invoke-rc.d: initscript prosody, action "start" failed. dpkg:
error processing prosody (--install):  subprocess installed
post-installation script returned error exit status 1 Processing
triggers for man-db ... Processing triggers for ureadahead ... Errors
were encountered while processing:  prosody
```

Thanks a lot for your patience and answers.

Comment: Any reason 5.1.2 from the Ubuntu repository doesn't work?

Comment: Good to know.  Is there a question you wanted to ask?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
```

Comment: Did not work. same error.

Comment: I noticed all those libraries are installed. I get this "liblua5.1-expat0 is already the newest version".Main issue is : **Prosody was unable to find luaexpat**